# php calling mail and failing

Tags: php, email

i am trying to set up a home page with an email form, where i can fill out email address and subject and comments and the php page will run
    mail -s my@email.com $comments
how can I do this via php to call the linux command?

thanks in advance

Comment: Won't `mail()` work for you? http://www.php.net/mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mail("youremail@domain.com","Subject","The message content");`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use PHP's own [`mail()`](http://php.net/mail) function?